# Zoom into a lat/long in highchart maps

Tags: charts, highcharts

i am not able to get x, y coordinates using fromLatLonToPoint to zoom into the expected location. x and y returns 0 and null.

I want to focus to lat/long of -74.0472251, 40.6908614.

```
       events: {
                load: function () {
                console.log(this.fromLatLonToPoint({
                     lat: 40.6908614,
                     lon: -74.0472251
                  }));
                    this.mapZoom(0.1, -74.0472251, 40.6908614);
                }
            }
```

here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/varghees/s9mqcefp/388/

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: I can see this error on the console "Map does not support latitude/longitude
The loaded map does not support latitude/longitude functionality. This is only supported with maps from the official Highmaps map collection from version 1.1.0 onwards. If you are using a custom map, consider using the Proj4js library to convert between projections."

Comment: Do you have any example using proj4js library to load custom map?

Comment: Hello CrazyProgrammer, you can find instructions on how to use proj4js library here: http://proj4js.org/

Comment: @ppotaczek yes i also tried but still it not works. i need to transform lat lon to coordinates? Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Hi @heart hacker, Plase check the Highcharts docs about Latitude/longitude for custom maps: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/latlon